# FAIL: Configuration for 'config' failed because of UnavailableShardsException[[.opendistro_security][0] primary shard is not active

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elk, amazon-elasticsearch, elasticsearch-opendistro

I was trying to configure opendistro elastic search by my own certificates.

when i did a curl to esip:9200 the response was

Open Distro Security not initialized.

Later when i tried to run security admin.sh for initializing security the error was like this

```
Open Distro Security Admin v7
Will connect to localhost:9300 ... done
Connected as CN=master
Elasticsearch Version: 7.8.0
Open Distro Security Version: 1.9.0.0
Contacting elasticsearch cluster 'elasticsearch' ...
Clustername: elasticsearch
Clusterstate: RED
Number of nodes: 1
Number of data nodes: 1
.opendistro_security index already exists, so we do not need to create one.
ERR: .opendistro_security index state is RED.
Populate config from /Users/jk/Desktop/ELK 7.9.0/opendistroforelasticsearch-1.9.0/plugins/opendistro_security/securityconfig
Will update '_doc/config' with plugins/opendistro_security/securityconfig/config.yml 
   FAIL: Configuration for 'config' failed because of UnavailableShardsException[[.opendistro_security][0] primary shard is not active Timeout: [1m], request: [BulkShardRequest [[.opendistro_security][0]] containing [index {[.opendistro_security][_doc][config], source[n/a, actual length: [3.7kb], max length: 2kb]}] and a refresh]]
Will update '_doc/roles' with plugins/opendistro_security/securityconfig/roles.yml 
   FAIL: Configuration for 'roles' failed because of NodeClosedException[node closed {master}{FXhShYtXTIOatM7kb36ePQ}{sxggZ8ceRHu4maB_ARDaBQ}{192.168.0.108}{192.168.0.108:9300}{dmr}]
Will update '_doc/rolesmapping' with plugins/opendistro_security/securityconfig/roles_mapping.yml 
WARNING: JAVA_HOME not set, will use /usr/bin/java
Open Distro Security Admin v7
Will connect to localhost:9300 ... done
Connected as CN=master
Elasticsearch Version: 7.8.0
Open Distro Security Version: 1.9.0.0
Contacting elasticsearch cluster 'elasticsearch' ...
Clustername: elasticsearch
Clusterstate: RED
Number of nodes: 1
Number of data nodes: 1
.opendistro_security index already exists, so we do not need to create one.
ERR: .opendistro_security index state is RED.
Populate config from /Users/jk/Desktop/ELK 7.9.0/opendistroforelasticsearch-1.9.0/plugins/opendistro_security/securityconfig
Will update '_doc/config' with plugins/opendistro_security/securityconfig/config.yml 
   FAIL: Configuration for 'config' failed because of UnavailableShardsException[[.opendistro_security][0] primary shard is not active Timeout: [1m], request: [BulkShardRequest [[.opendistro_security][0]] containing [index {[.opendistro_security][_doc][config], source[n/a, actual length: [3.7kb], max length: 2kb]}] and a refresh]]
Will update '_doc/roles' with plugins/opendistro_security/securityconfig/roles.yml 
   FAIL: Configuration for 'roles' failed because of UnavailableShardsException[[.opendistro_security][0] primary shard is not active Timeout: [1m], request: [BulkShardRequest [[.opendistro_security][0]] containing [index {[.opendistro_security][_doc][roles], source[{"roles":"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"}]}] and a refresh]]
Will update '_doc/rolesmapping' with plugins/opendistro_security/securityconfig/roles_mapping.yml 
   FAIL: Configuration for 'rolesmapping' failed because of UnavailableShardsException[[.opendistro_security][0] primary shard is not active Timeout: [1m], request: [BulkShardRequest [[.opendistro_security][0]] containing [index {[.opendistro_security][_doc][rolesmapping], source[{"rolesmapping":"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"}]}] and a refresh]]
Will update '_doc/internalusers' with plugins/opendistro_security/securityconfig/internal_users.yml 
   FAIL: Configuration for 'internalusers' failed because of UnavailableShardsException[[.opendistro_security][0] primary shard is not active Timeout: [1m], request: [BulkShardRequest [[.opendistro_security][0]] containing [index {[.opendistro_security][_doc][internalusers], source[{"internalusers":"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"}]}] and a refresh]]
Will update '_doc/actiongroups' with plugins/opendistro_security/securityconfig/action_groups.yml 
   FAIL: Configuration for 'actiongroups' failed because of UnavailableShardsException[[.opendistro_security][0] primary shard is not active Timeout: [1m], request: [BulkShardRequest [[.opendistro_security][0]] containing [index {[.opendistro_security][_doc][actiongroups], source[{"actiongroups":"eyJfbWV0YSI6eyJ0eXBlIjoiYWN0aW9uZ3JvdXBzIiwiY29uZmlnX3ZlcnNpb24iOjJ9fQ=="}]}] and a refresh]]
Will update '_doc/tenants' with plugins/opendistro_security/securityconfig/tenants.yml 
   FAIL: Configuration for 'tenants' failed because of UnavailableShardsException[[.opendistro_security][0] primary shard is not active Timeout: [1m], request: [BulkShardRequest [[.opendistro_security][0]] containing [index {[.opendistro_security][_doc][tenants], source[{"tenants":"eyJfbWV0YSI6eyJ0eXBlIjoidGVuYW50cyIsImNvbmZpZ192ZXJzaW9uIjoyfSwiYWRtaW5fdGVuYW50Ijp7InJlc2VydmVkIjpmYWxzZSwiZGVzY3JpcHRpb24iOiJEZW1vIHRlbmFudCBmb3IgYWRtaW4gdXNlciJ9fQ=="}]}] and a refresh]]
Will update '_doc/nodesdn' with plugins/opendistro_security/securityconfig/nodes_dn.yml 
   FAIL: Configuration for 'nodesdn' failed because of UnavailableShardsException[[.opendistro_security][0] primary shard is not active Timeout: [1m], request: [BulkShardRequest [[.opendistro_security][0]] containing [index {[.opendistro_security][_doc][nodesdn], source[{"nodesdn":"eyJfbWV0YSI6eyJ0eXBlIjoibm9kZXNkbiIsImNvbmZpZ192ZXJzaW9uIjoyfX0="}]}] and a refresh]]
ERR: cannot upload configuration, see errors above
```

Comment: Issue is that the .opendistro_security index is red. You need to root cause why the index cannot be assigned to any shards. You can hit the explain api on this index to find the reason. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster-allocation-explain.html

Comment: Hello, i am facing the same issue, i would like to know if you resolved the issue ? if yes, how please? thank you!